# Should I correct the DF in the Li-Mak (1994) test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, garch, degrees-of-freedom, diagnostic

I am doing diagnostic tests on a GJR-GARCH(p,q) model. I have carried out both the Li-Mak (1994) test and the Ljung-Box test, knowing that the latter was not made for GARCH models. The test statistics are almost identical between the two tests.

In the Ljung-Box test, it is common to correct the degrees of freedom (DF) for pre-estimated parameters by subtracting (p+q).
Should I do the same when working with the Li-Mak test?

I have not found any literature on the Li-Mak test that suggests correcting the degrees of freedom, but given that the two tests give very similar test statistics, it feels odd correcting only the Ljung-Box and not the Li-Mak.

Alternatively, can anyone provide a reference to the theoretical justification for correcting the Ljung-Box test? Then I can perhaps infer the answer myself.